# NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (strided_slice_1:0) to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

- python version 3.8.10
- numpy version 1.22.4
- tensorflow version 2.9.1

My code:

```
net  = keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
)
net.trainable = False
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="avg_pool")(net.output)
x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(2)(x)
model = keras.Model(net.inputs,x)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[f1_score])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20,batch_size=64, validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))
```

The error:

```
 NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (strided_slice_1:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.
```

I already checked for similar problems, and I tried to downgrade NumPy and TensorFlow, but the error persists.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Could you provide a sample data of `x_train`, `y_train`, `x_validation`, `y_validation`, `f1_score` to help with reproducing the example?

Comment: Oh looks like this is an [open issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9706) with tensor flow, could you try the workaround mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9706#issuecomment-782841778) to see if it resolves the issue